# Effect of "windows defender is taking action to clean detected malware"

Tags: security, anti-virus, windows-defender

Sometimes I get this message, but when I look at the history of windows defender, I see nothing. I am scared that windows is mistaking something important for a malware and deleting it without me knowing. Can I trust the windows defender history?

Answer (score 0):

Windows defender will surely not be deleting any of your personal files (unless you're a hacker and all your files are viruses). Many others have had this problem and you don't see anything in the History tab because Windows defender keeps detecting the same virus only in a different locations, and so does not make a history entry.

If you are really into security, I suggest you get a really good anti-virus like [Bitdefender](http://www.bitdefender.com) or [Norton](http://norton.com).

Comment: sometimes antivirus programs mistake obscure (but not dangerous) tools for viruses

Comment: @grdgfgr That is true, but it very rarely happens. BTW, What rather obscure tools do you have on your computer?